# how does fuser report on sockets as non-root user?

Tags: linux, sockets, fuser

I'm trying to use fuser to find the pids of processes I own which have certain TCP ports open.

In the fuser man page it says:

... The most common time this problem occurs is when looking for TCP or UDP sockets when running fuser as a non-root user. In this case fuser will report no access. ...

However, on my Ubuntu box, fuser does report sockets open for processes that I own, e.g.:

perl -MIO::Socket 'IO::Socket::INET->new(Listen => 10, LocalPort => 3000)' &

fuser -n tcp 3000

Question: how are things set up to allow this to happen? Is it a kernel config option?

Thanks!

Note: the question is: how are some linux distros configured so that fuser will report processes owning sockets when fuser is run as a normal user? One one Ubuntu distro "fuser -n tcp 3000" will report a process if I own the process, yet on another linux distro (I think Centos) it won't report the process even if I own it.

Answer (score 1):

`fuser` goes through the `/proc` file system ([`proc(5)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html)) working through the `/proc/[pid]/fd/` directory and checking the file descriptors. Processes owned by you have corresponding `/proc` entries again owned by you. This allows you to check your processes, but not others.

One very useful tool to see what given program is doing is [`strace(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace). For example, you can see what system calls, and with what arguments, are done by the `fuser`:

```
~$ strace fuser -n tcp 3000
```

Comment: Hi - thanks, but that's not exactly what I'm asking. I think there is a kernel config option which allows fuser to see/or not see processes which own a particular socket. On one linux distro fuser can "see" my own processes, but on another distro "fuser -n tcp 3000" will not report anything even if I own the process.

Comment: @perlman, is `SELINUX` enabled on the machine that will not permit `fuser` to see your own processes?